# javascript regex remove quotes if number with no hyphens

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I want to remove quotes only if the match expression is a number and has no hyphen after it. Right now am doing this:

```
$obj.replace(/"([\d.-]+)"/g,"$1")
```

Where $obj is a JSON.stringify o/p. How do I modify the regex to remove quotes if the number is not followed by a hyphen So "12" should get transformed to 12 but "44-45" should remain as it is.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `-` from the character class: numbers don't have minuses in them. To allow an optional minus sign at the beginning only, add `-?` to the front.

```
$obj.replace(/"(-?[\d.]+)"/g,"$1")
```

While we're here, you might also want to check that there's only one decimal point, and leave a string like `"1.2.3.4"` alone.

```
$obj.replace(/"(-?(\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+))"/g,"$1")
//                 ^^^^^^^^^           a number with optional decimal places
//                           ^^^^^     decimal point followed by digits
```